issue with video_player in flutter
I am new to flutter and was creating a flutter app where i can play video coming from network url.I used video_player package for it and it is working fine until a issue or error came.
the issue is that while video is playing on my android device(I have not tested on ios) and if my device screen gets turned off or sleep and then when i reopen it then flutter shows an exception
:-
Bad state error : future already completed and after this error, my app gets freezed and will not respond to anything.
i am adding code i wrote for video player here.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoScreen> createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late VideoPlayerController videoController;
  @override
  void initState() {
   initializeVideoPlayer();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // Pause the video when the app goes to the background
      videoController.pause();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // Reinitialize video player when the app resumes
      if (videoController.value.isInitialized) {
        videoController.play();
      } else {
        initializeVideoPlayer(); // Reinitialize if it's not initialized
      }
      // Optionally, autoplay when resumed
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final devicewidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final deviceheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox.expand(
                child: videoController.value.isBuffering ||
                        videoController.value.isInitialized == false
                    ? Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                      )
                    : VideoPlayer(videoController)),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: deviceheight * 0.80,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (videoController.value.isPlaying) {
                                videoController.pause();
                              } else {
                                videoController.play();
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            videoController.value.isPlaying
                                ? Icons.pause
                                : Icons.play_arrow,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            size: 30,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 5,
                    width: devicewidth * 0.8,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    child: Slider(
                      value:
                          videoController.value.position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        videoController
                            .seekTo(Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
                      },
                      thumbColor: Colors.yellow,
                      max: videoController.value.duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                      min: 0,
                      label:
                          videoController.value.position.inSeconds.toString(),
                      activeColor: Colors.yellow,
                      divisions: videoController.value.duration.inSeconds == 0
                          ? 1
                          : videoController.value.duration.inSeconds,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    size: 20,
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    try {
      videoController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
          "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"))
       
        ..initialize().then((value) {
          setState(() {
            videoController.play();
          });
        });
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Something went wrong")));
    }
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // TODO: implement deactivate

    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    videoController.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
      }
    }

I tried things I got on chatgpt and other ai models as you can see above adding applifecyclestate widgebindings.instance , etc but it still did not work.
I hope to find a workable solution for this error here.
